# Install older version of snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I need to install version 4.7.0 of snakemake, but I cannot find it. Could you please tell me where can I get old versions of the software? I tried the bitbucket repository but I could not find any other than the latest version.

Comment: you can always find it via conda on the bioconda repository !

Comment: Or you can [find it on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/src/8086d58063c1b4b544d89b68cd7098a304c56b08) :)

Answer (score 1):

It is available through conda:

```
$  conda search -c bioconda -f snakemake=4.7.0
Loading channels: \  conda search -c bioconda -f snakemake=4.7
# Name                  Version           Build  Channel
snakemake                 4.7.0          py35_0  bioconda
snakemake                 4.7.0          py36_0  bioconda
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pip?

`pip install snakemake==4.7.0`

For source code download: https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/downloads/?tab=tags